# Phonegap app: Problems with Facebook login via native SDK or via CordovaWebView

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

**Our project**

We have one responsive website (based on Meteor.js) for our product. The user authentication will be done with Facebook Logins.
To have a store presents, we created Phonegap apps for IOS and Android. This apps basically load our website (remote).  Furthermore, we try to use some plugins to enhance user experience (e.g. native Facebook Single-sign on).

--> Central point of this approach: we only have one common website for all platforms (web, android and IOS). The website is able to differentiate between the clients and loads whatever is needed (e.g. Phonegap.js).

**Problem Facebook Login**

For the Facebook login, we have different scenarios for mobile users:

1. User opens the website with a normal browser and logs into Facebook
2. User has our App and Facebook App installed (native Facebook single sign on)
3. User has our App and no Facebook App installed (Login within the cordovaWebView)

Szenario 1 is no problem at all. But we struggle with Scenario 2 and 3.

**Try with Phonegap Facebook plugin**

We tried to use the official Phonegap plugin (https://github.com/Phonegap/Phonegap-Facebook-plugin). We spend days if not weeks with this plugin. In short: it’s a mess and not stable for Android and IOS. With some versions and hacks we can run our Phonegap app, access the native Facebook app and login really easy.

But if someone has the Facebook app not installed, the Cordova WebView (InAppBrowser plugin installed) opens a pop up for a normal browser login, and we end up with a blank / white screen. There are several workarounds documented for this on Stackoverflow – from native hacks within the WebView to JavaScript hacks :-).

Because of the unstable / messy plugin and the not working web login within the WebView, we gave up with this approach.

**Current approach**

A simple workaround is the Phonegap Facebook InAppBrowser Plugin (in short FIAB, https://github.com/caiovaccaro/Phonegap.Facebook.inappbrowser). With this FIAB plugin, Scenario 3 is working fine. For now, we don’t support Scenario 2 with native Facebook Single Sign on.

**Looking for tips, help or other feedback**

Is somebody out there with similar problems or with other approaches? Does somebody has some tips or solutions? Is there something I’m not seeing? Should not be so difficult, itns’t it? :-) Did someone already try to use the Phonegap Facebook plugin combined with the FIAB plugin?

I’m really looking forward for some know-how exchange in this topic.

Thank you very much
thomas

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same issue with the white screen for the WebView authentication when using phonegap-facebook-plugin.

Comment: Hi Mike, not really. We tried many things, but we don't have a stable solution for IOS and Android for the moment :-(

Comment: Thanks for the link to facebook.inappbrowser - exactly what I was looking for, for exactly the same reasons!

Comment: We just finished a Cordova project with social login requirements. Phonegap-facebook-plugin worked fine for us. There were some gotchas, but in the end we got it working. What issues are you having?

Comment: I know it's too late an answer -but were you able to solve this?

Comment: Hi @LohithKorupolu, sadly we could not solve it. Actually we stopped to work on it. But I could imange that in the meantime new ways (or new Plugins) might be available. Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Phonegap/Phonegap-Facebook-plugin should work fine. A lot of work has been going on since last year. It is also up-to-date with Facebook SDK 4. This post also, has no clear question. I suggest to moderators that this thread should be closed:

- out-of-date
- not specific

Source: I'm an Official Facebook Phonegap Plugin Maintainer.